# Xquery for determining all nodes are unique

Tags: xpath, xquery

Assuming a document such as:

```
<a>
 <b>TEST1</b>
 <b>TEST2</b>
 <b>TEST1</b>
</a>
```

Is there any Xquery one liner you can use to check that all values of b are unique without having to run a for-each of on the doc? So for example in the above document it would return false, whereas in the below document it would return true

```
<a>
 <b>TEST1</b>
 <b>TEST2</b>
 <b>TEST3</b>
</a>
```

Comment: There are some options.. what version of xquery is this (1/2/3)?

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach but using [`empty()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-empty) might be a bit more efficient :

```
empty(/a/b[. = following-sibling::b])
```

`empty()` returns `true` if the parameter expression yields empty sequence, and returns `false` otherwise. So in this case, if there found sibling `b` with the same value a.k.a a dupe, `empty()` will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for sibling with same value e,g:

```
 count(b[preceding-sibling::b = .])
```

or to get true or false:

```
not(b[preceding-sibling::b = .])
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is probably

```
count(b) = count(distinct-values(b))
```

The other solutions you have been given are likely to be quadratic in the number of test elements, whereas this is likely to be O(n log n).

(However, this is on the assumption that duplicates are rare. If duplicates are very common, then some kind of fold operation might find them faster, especially with XQuery 3.0).